# How to host my MVC4 website inside folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, iis

I have created a folder in root directory in my server and I have uploaded my website in folder which is developed in MVC4, but its not running and giving the error:

> It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the virtual directory to an application. There are some instruction on how to do this [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772042%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: thank you so much for helping me on this. it worked for me. great efforts